# Recycle view scroll doesn't work

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have a navigation activity, where i also have a recycle view and a toolbar, to use the toolbar and the recycle view on this view, I created a separate XML layout like this:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.PlantFeed">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/emerald"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:id="@+id/recycleView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:backgroundTint="#f1c40f"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

    <include layout="@layout/content_plant_feed" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

After this I included this layout on my main activity like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_plant_feed"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_plant_feed"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_plant_feed_drawer"
        android:background="@color/white"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I am populating the recycler view with data of my database using also cardview, the thing is that with this approach (using include) my recycle view doesn't scroll, i have a lot of items but it always show just 4 of them.

**my adapter:**

```
public class PlantFeedAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PlantFeedAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private OnItemClickListener listener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onRowClick(int position, String name, int id, View view);
        void onTitleClicked(int position, int id, View clickedview);
        void onImageClicked(int position,int id, View clickedview);
        void onReportClicked(int position, int id,String name, View clickedview);
        void onUserIconClicked(int position, int id, View clickedview);
        void onUsernameClicked(int position, int id, View clickedview);
        void onAvaliationClicked(int position, int id,String name, View clickedview);

    }

    private ArrayList<PlantPhotoUser> photos;
    private Context context;

    public PlantFeedAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<PlantPhotoUser> photos, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.photos = photos;
        this.context = context;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public PlantFeedAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.plant_feed_row, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final PlantFeedAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
        viewHolder.name.setText(photos.get(i).getSpecie());
        viewHolder.username.setText(photos.get(i).getUsernName());
        viewHolder.data.setText(photos.get(i).getDate().split("T")[0]);
        Log.d("data123",(photos.get(i).getDate().toString()));

        final String urlFoto = "http://10.0.2.2:3000/" + photos.get(i).getPath();

        viewHolder.userIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.onUserIconClicked(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), photos.get(i).getUserId(), view);
                }
            }
        });

        viewHolder.username.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.onUsernameClicked(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(),photos.get(i).getUserId(), view);
                }
            }
        });

        viewHolder.plantImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.onImageClicked(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), photos.get(i).getIdPlant(), view);
                }
            }
        });


        viewHolder.name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(listener != null){
                    listener.onTitleClicked(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(),photos.get(i).getIdPlant(),v);
                }
            }
        });

        viewHolder.reportImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(listener != null){
                    listener.onReportClicked(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(),photos.get(i).getIdPlant(),photos.get(i).getSpecie(),v);
                }
            }
        });

        viewHolder.avaliationFoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(listener != null){
                    listener.onAvaliationClicked(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(),photos.get(i).getIdPlant(),photos.get(i).getSpecie(),v);
                }
            }
        });



        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(urlFoto)
                .resize(300, 300)
                .into(viewHolder.plantImg);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return photos.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private TextView name;
        private ImageView userIcon;
        private TextView avaliationFoto;
        private ImageView plantImg;
        private ImageView foto;
        private TextView username;
        private ImageView reportImage;
        private TextView data;
        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            data = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.data);
            name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.plantName);
            avaliationFoto = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.Avaliation);
            userIcon = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.userIcon);
            plantImg = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.plantPhoto);;
            username = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.username);
            reportImage = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.cameraForbiden);

        }
    }


}
```

**activity code:**

```
public class PlantFeed extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,PlantFeedAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

    //initialize fields

    String token;

    ArrayList<PlantPhotoUser> photos = new ArrayList<>();

    VolleyService mVolleyService;
    IResult mResultCallback = null;
    final String GETREQUEST = "GETCALL";

    final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:3000/fotos";

    String date;
    String lat;
    String lon;
    String alt;

    PlantFeedAdapter plantFeedAdapter;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_plant_feed);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(PlantFeed.this,CameraCapture.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycleView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager((new LinearLayoutManager(this)));
        plantFeedAdapter = new PlantFeedAdapter(getApplicationContext(), photos,PlantFeed.this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(plantFeedAdapter);

        token = checkForToken();

        initVolleyCallback();

        mVolleyService = new VolleyService(mResultCallback,this);

        mVolleyService.getDataVolley(GETREQUEST,URL,token);

    }

    void initVolleyCallback(){
        mResultCallback = new IResult() {
            @Override
            public void notifySuccess(String requestType,JSONObject response) {
                Log.d("HELLL","hi1");
            }

            @Override
            public void notifySuccess(String requestType, JSONArray response) {
                PlantPhotoUser plantPhotoUser;
                Log.d("HELLLL","hi");
                for (int i=0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        Log.d("objeto",object.toString());

                        int userId = object.getInt("userId");
                        Log.d("objeto",String.valueOf(userId));
                        String username = object.getJSONObject("user").getString("username");
                        Log.d("objeto",String.valueOf(username));
                        int plantId = object.getInt("plantId");
                        Log.d("objeto",String.valueOf(plantId));
                        String specie = object.getJSONObject("plant").getString("specie");
                        Log.d("objeto",String.valueOf(specie));

                        String path = object.getString("image");
                        Log.d("objeto",String.valueOf(path));
                        int fotoId = object.getInt("id");

                        if(object.getString("date") != null){
                            date = object.getString("date");
                        }

                        if(object.getString("lat") != null){
                            lat = object.getString("lat");
                        }

                        if(object.getString("lon") != null){
                            lon = object.getString("lon");
                        }

                        if(object.getString("altitude") != null){
                            alt = object.getString("altitude");
                        }

                        plantPhotoUser = new PlantPhotoUser(fotoId,plantId,userId,path,specie,date,lat,lon,alt,username);
                        photos.add(plantPhotoUser);


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                plantFeedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void notifyError(String requestType,VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("FAIL",error.toString());
            }
        };
    }

    public String checkForToken() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("user", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String tokenKey = getResources().getString(R.string.token);
        String token = sharedPref.getString(getString(R.string.token), tokenKey); // take the token
        return token;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        Intent i = new Intent(PlantFeed.this,UserProfile.class);
        startActivity(i);
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.plant_feed, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            Intent i = new Intent(PlantFeed.this,CameraCapture.class);
            startActivity(i);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
            Intent i = new Intent(PlantFeed.this,PlantFeed.class);
            startActivity(i);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
            Intent i = new Intent(PlantFeed.this,FamilyLibrary.class);
            startActivity(i);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRowClick(int position, String name, int id, View view) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTitleClicked(int position, int id, View clickedview) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this,PhotosForPlant.class);
        i.putExtra("plantId",String.valueOf(id));
        startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
    public void onImageClicked(int position, int id, View clickedview) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this,PhotosForPlant.class);
        i.putExtra("plantId",String.valueOf(id));
        startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReportClicked(int position, int id, String name, View clickedview) {
        Log.d("HELLLO","HELLOO");
        showDialogReport(id,name);
    }


    @Override
    public void onUserIconClicked(int position, int id, View clickedview) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this,UserProfile.class);
        i.putExtra("userId",id);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUsernameClicked(int position, int id, View clickedview) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this,UserProfile.class);
        i.putExtra("userId",id);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAvaliationClicked(int position, int id, String name, View clickedview) {

    }
```

Any tip?

Comment: show ur adapter declaration part too

Comment: updated, but the data shows well, the only problem is with the scroll

Comment: i asked u to show me the part where u initialized adapter

Comment: post ur activity where u initialized this adapter

Comment: sorry already edited

Comment: should i put navView and included toolbar inside?

Comment: no need of that,ur xml looks good as of now

Comment: but scroll still don't work

Comment: i just cannot find the issue

Comment: i have a recycle view inside that include, and i want that recycle view to be scrolable

Comment: check my answer and inform me what happens

Comment: did it resolve?? @Cris dois